# Where can I find the rules for 7 Wonders and its expansions?

Tags: 7-wonders, reference

Are the rules for *7 Wonders* and the expansions available online?

Comment: (Side note: See the Meta question: [Is it okay to ask if rule books are available online?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/981/3532))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can find them on the offical website of *Repos Production* (rprod.com):

#### *7 Wonders* base game

http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download-2 (there you can find the *Quick Rules*, too)

- [Czech (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_CZ_COLOR.pdf)
- [Danish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_DK_COLOR.pdf)
- [Dutch (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_NL_COLOR.pdf)
- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_COLOR.pdf)
- [Finnish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_FIN_COLOR.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_FR_COLOR.pdf)
- [German (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_DE_COLOR.pdf)
- [Greek (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_GR_COLOR.pdf)
- [Hungarian (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_HU_COLOR.pdf)
- [Italian (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_IT_COLOR.pdf)
- [Japanese (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_JP_COLOR.pdf)
- [Korean (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_KOR_COLOR.pdf)
- [Norwegian (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_NOR_COLOR.pdf)
- [Polish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_PL_COLOR.pdf)
- [Slovak (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_SL_COLOR.pdf)
- [Spanish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_SP_COLOR.pdf)
- [Swedish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_SW_COLOR.pdf)

#### *Leaders* expansion

http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download-3

- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_LEADERS_RULES_EN_COLOR.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_LEADERS_RULES_FR_COLOR.pdf)
- [German (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_LEADERS_RULES_DE_COLOR.pdf)

#### *Cities* expansion

http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download

- [Dutch (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_NL.pdf)
- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_EN.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_FR.pdf)
- [German (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_DE.pdf)
- [Japanese (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_JP.pdf)
- [Spanish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_CITIES_RULES_SP.pdf)

#### *Wonder Pack* extension

http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download-12

- [Dutch (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_NL.pdf)
- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_US.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_FR.pdf)
- [German (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_DE.pdf)
- [Spanish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_SP.pdf)

#### *Babel* extension

http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download-18 (there you can find the *Quick Rules*, too)

- [Dutch (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-Nl.pdf)
- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-En.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-FR.pdf)
- [German (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-De.pdf)
- [Italian (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-it.pdf)
- [Japanese (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-Jp.pdf)
- [Polish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-Pl.pdf)
- [Spanish (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7W-Babel-Rules-Sp.pdf)

---

#### Official FAQ

- [**English** (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/FAQ_USA_7W.pdf)
- [French (PDF)](http://rprod.com/uploads/7WONDERS_FAQ_FR.pdf)

Comment: I wish there was a combined rules... I've got both expansions, and having to flip through 3 books to find the card you're looking for can be a pain.