# Choose from discard pile ability: put into play simultaneously?

Tags: 7-wonders

The [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532) for the *Wonder Pack* say:

> If multiple players take cards from the discard pile during a given turn, the resolution order is the following: Halikarnassos, The Great Wall, Manneken Pis, Salomon and finally, Courtesan’s Guild

Let’s say Alice plays this ability from *Halikarnassos* and Bob plays it from *The Great Wall*.

Alice chooses a card from the discard pile. **Does she have to put it in play before Bob chooses a card?** Or do they put their cards in play simultaneously?

Answer (score 6):

**The cards are taken secretly from the discard, and then put into play simultaneously**

The quote from the [Wonder Pack rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_US.pdf) should be taken literally. When they use the term, "resolution order" they are specifically speaking of what order to resolve the actions in the previous conditional: (I.e. multiple players **taking** cards from the discard pile.)

> If multiple players take cards from the discard pile during a given turn, the resolution order is the following: Halikarnassos, The Great Wall, Manneken Pis, Salomon and finally, Courtesan’s Guild

Cards are always played simultaneously, so some way to resolve conflicts between multiple players taking conflicting actions is necessary. Take for example the [original rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_COLOR.pdf) (page 5, 8):

> **Overview of an Age** - [...] Each Age is made up of 6 game turns. During each turn the players **put into play a single card, simultaneously**.
>
> **The Mausoleum of Halicarnassus** - the player can look through all of the cards discarded since the beginning of the game (those discarded for coins as well as those discarded at the end of an age), pick one, and build it for free.
>
> **Clarification :** this special ability takes place at the end of the turn in which this stage is built. If players discard cards this turn (as in the case of the 6th turn of an age), the player can also choose from among them.

The same rules text is in the [Leaders Expansion](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_LEADERS_RULES_EN_COLOR.pdf) (page 4, 7):

> **Recruitment Phase** - During this phase, each player will play one of their Leader cards. The cards are chosen secretly by each player, **then revealed simultaneously to be played.**
>
> **Solomon** - Once Solomon enters play, the player can choose an Age card from the discard pile and put it in play for free.

The Leaders rules also only notes that Halicarnassus **chooses** its card before Solomon, not that it plays the card before Solomon.

> **Leader: Solomon**
>
> *Q: What happens if Solomon enters play in the same turn in which Halicarnassus builds a Wonder stage?*
>
> A: Halicarnassus chooses its card from the discard pile before Solomon.

Comment: It should also be noted that the **Bazar and Vineyard** count Brown/Gray cards respectively that are built during the "same turn", and Halicarnassus's ability occurs at the end of the same turn its wonder stage is built.

Answer (score 3):

There is no step between "choose a card from the discards" and "put the card into play": the various play-from-discard abilities are a single-step action. The rules text uses the phrase "resolution order," so you should fully resolve each player's play-from-discard ability before moving onto the next player with a play-from-discard ability. **Alice chooses a discarded card and puts it into play before Bob even looks at the discards.**

In general, 7 Wonders doesn't break things into discrete steps, so there's no sense in inventing extra steps for this particular case. I agree that there *is* a very small advantage for Bob here (slightly bigger if Alice is a neighbor), but that's roughly balanced by Alice getting first pick of the discards.

Comment: I disagree, everywhere else in 7-wonders, buildings enter play simultaneously. My guess is this rule for "resolution" is in regard to choosing a card from the discard. Players need a specific order to handle that. Players choose their card from the discard in that order (keeping the chosen card face down), and then reveal and put into play simultaneously. Unfortunately, I haven't found an official FAQ that confirms this interpretation, but it follows other building rules like how buildings count all other building put into play during the same turn.

Comment: Post that as an answer, then. I very much see your point, but I disagree; I don't think that the various special abilities are intended to be at all complicated. If Halikarnassos is supposed to go first, then let Halikarnassos go first and be done first. Don't confuse the issue by having Halikarnassos do half of something, wait for other players, and then do the other half.