# In 7 Wonders, when using a Leader to build Babylon (B)'s second stage before Age 3

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

With the addition of the *Leaders* expansion, you can use your leaders to build your wonder.

If you build Babylon (B)'s second stage (which allows you to play the card you would normally discard) with your third Age Leader, can you use this ability to play your fourth Leader or must it be used to play a third Age card?

As the fourth Leader would normally be discarded, the question was raised as we were playing tonight. I'm not sure how to answer it since, if you were using a Leader in any other Age, you would not be able to play another Leader as you would not be discarding a Leader at that time.

Answer (score 7):

No, you are not allowed to play a Leader.

From the base game [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532), page 9:

> *The Hanging Gardens of Babylon*
>   · the second stage gives the player the option of playing their **seventh 
>   Age card** instead of discarding it.

From the Leader [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532), page 3:

> *Leader Cards*
>   The Leaders (white cards) are a new card category. They are **not added to the Age cards** and have a different back to set them apart.

See the bold parts: Babylon (B) allows you to play an *Age card*, but Leaders are not part of the *Age card* set.