# When can I activate the special Halicarnassus effect?

Tags: 7-wonders

[image]

The rules say what the effect does but not when to use it.

- Once per era?
- At the time the wonder upgrade is done?
- At the end of the game?
- Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules do say it (English base game rules, page 8 and also page 9, for the wonder *The Mausoleum of Halicarnassus*):

> Clarification: this special ability takes place at the end of the turn in which
>   this stage is built. If players discard cards this turn (as in the case of the 6th
>   turn of an age), the player can also choose from among them.

So when you build this wonder stage, you wait until everyone finished their action, and then you go through the discard pile and [build](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/9444/3532) one of its cards for free. [One time only](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/14999/3532) (per wonder stage).

Special cases:

- [if others use the same ability in the same turn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/12961/3532) (tl;dr: there is a defined resolution order)
- [if the Babylon (B) player discards the 7th card for money](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/10952/3532) (tl;dr: it gets added to the discard pile *before* the Halicarnassus player goes through it)