# 7 wonders: builder's chambers

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-cities

If I build the Builder's Chambers at the same time as someone builds his first wonder stage, should he be charged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume you mean *Builders’ Union*, where other players have to pay 1 coin to the bank for each Wonder stage they built.)

**Yes**, players have to pay also for stages built in the same turn.

From the [*Cities* rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532) about Debts (page 4):

> Important : monetary losses are always resolved at the end of a turn, after players have played their cards, possibly having paid for trade and/or obtained money...

Comment: In the rules it says Union. On the card, it says Chambers.

Comment: @Lost1: Ah okay, didn’t know that (I’m playing with German cards).