# How does the effect of tile 22 (from Tower of Babel) apply to tokens (from Great Projects)?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-babel

In the *Babel* rules, under the section "Playing with the other expansions", it says ([English PDF, page 7](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532)):

> If you play with the Tower of Babel expansion, the effect of tiles 19 and 22 also apply to Conflict tokens from the Great Projects.

Tile 19 modifies the "taking of military Victory tokens".

Tile 22 modifies the "taking of military Defeat tokens".

While the Great Projects expansion has a reward token where you get Victory tokens (so the effect of tile 19 is clear), there is no reward nor penality token where you get Defeat tokens.

So when would the effect of tile 22 "apply to Conflict tokens from the Great Projects"?

Answer (score 1):

Despite not having, yet, a Project that hands out defeat tokens as penalties, the phrase "*apply to Conflict tokens from the Great Projects*" is still in the rules just in case a relevant Great Project will be released, either as a promo or in a future expansion. That's my best guess.