# Maecenas and Rome (B): are the extra Leaders also free?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

The Leader **Maecenas** allows to build Leaders for free ([*Leaders*, page 6](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532)):

> As soon as Maecenas enters play, his controlling player can recruit all of his or her future Leaders for free (during the *Recruitment* Phase), without having to pay their coin cost.

The Wonder **Rome (B)** allows in its second and third stage to build additional Leaders (*Leaders*, page 12):

> - The second stage is worth 3 victory points and the player can immediately put in play an extra Leader (by paying 2 coins less than its printed cost).
> - The third stage is worth 3 victory points and the player can immediately put in play an extra Leader (by paying 2 coins less than its printed cost).

**If the Rome (B) player has recruited Maecenas, can the additional Leaders (from the 2nd/3rd stage) be built for free?**

I wonder because it says "during the Recruitment Phase", but when building the wonder stages, you are not in the Recruitment Phase, are you? So this would mean that Maecenas’ effect doesn’t work for the extra Leaders, unless this is an oversight, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The recruitment phase is specifically at the beginning of an age before players have received cards.  I would agree that Maecenas would only get the bonus during this phase and not if leader is put in play by any other means.