# Ramses and Babel tile 23: are Guilds free or do you have to pay coins?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-babel, 7-wonders-leaders

If you have recruited the Leader **Ramses** and the Babel **tile 23** is active, can you build Guilds for free, or do you have to pay coins?

Leader Ramses: ([*Leaders*, page 6](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532))

> As soon as Ramses enters play, the player can build all of his or her Guilds for free, without having to pay their resource costs.

Babel tile 23 ([*Babel*, page 5](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532)):

> The construction of […] Guilds (purple cards) via resources is forbidden. Their construction requires a number of coins equal to the number of resources present in their construction cost. […]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Ramses in effect, guilds are still free. This is the reason Babel tile 23 specifies "construction of guilds via *resources*" is forbidden.

Antoine Bauza (the game's creator) [was asked this directly on his forums](http://www.antoinebauza.fr/?p=3568) this past December. The question was posed:

«When we built a guild with Ramses Leader in play but the tile Babel No. 23 (resources become parts payable) is also at stake, what's happening? The guild building is it paying off in parts or completely free in the end?»

To which he replied:

«Your Free guilds remain with Ramses (Free resource becomes free rooms)»