# 7 wonders Alexandria side A special ability

Tags: 7-wonders

I don't understand the special ability a player gains after building the second stage of Alexandria side A. Can someone explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add more detail about what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: Yes. So the person can get an extra element. How?

Comment: Do I physically get it, or just use it to buy a structure....

Comment: As Adama already explained, it's the same as if you obtained a card with those symbols.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you inquire about stage #2 of side A. According to the [Rules, p. 8](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/where-can-i-find-the-rules-for-7-wonders-and-its-expansions/10939#10939):

> the player gains a resource of their choice from the 4 Raw material types
>   [Stone, Clay, Wood, Ore] every turn.
>   Clarification : this resource cannot be sold through commerce.

In other words, each turn you have a wild, exclusive raw material at your disposal, for free, just like if you had bought the **Caravansary** Age II yellow card. Other players may not buy this resource.