# 7 Wonders (Cities Expansion): War from both sides due to Peace Tokens

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-cities

Just played my second game of 7 Wonders, after I impulse purchased it along with the Cities Expansion. As we play in a group of four, its not uncommon that two grab Peace Tokens during the same Age, resulting in only two people at the end to fight the war.

What happens in this situation? Does the war happen twice (IE loser gains two losses and the victor gains two wins)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once only. According to the [cities rulebook](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/where-can-i-find-the-rules-for-7-wonders-and-its-expansions?lq=1), p. 5:

> If there are ever only 2 players left during a conflict resolution, they only face each other once and each take a single token.

Comment: I don't know what will be worse, breaking the bad news to the person who beat me up twice, or then telling that the answer was actually in the rulebook which I was SURE I checked.