# Can you use Halicarnassus to build a duplicate card?

Tags: 7-wonders

As the title. If not, what happens if you build the wonder, say in Age II, and all the cards are duplicates of cards you've already built?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [base rule (p. 5)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/where-can-i-find-the-rules-for-7-wonders-and-its-expansions/10939#10939) of forbidding duplicate cards is always in effect: (emphasis mine)

> Important: a player can **never** build two identical structures (meaning those with the same name/the same illustration).

With Halikarnassos you are still "building" a card: (p. 9)

> the first stage is worth 2 victory points and the player can look at 
>   all of the cards discarded since the beginning of the game and **build** 
>   one for free

Therefore, the base rule is still in effect: you may not build a duplicate card. If all cards are duplicates, then you cannot build anything and you have just "wasted" your special ability; this has happened once to me.

Comment: Would it be permissible to turn it in for 3 coins?

Comment: @Bill N it's not legal in the first place to take the card. The ruling "if you build a duplicate you just discard it for $3" is just a house rule when someone builds a duplicate without the others noticing until it's too late. Strictly speaking, it's not a legal move.

Comment: @Adama, note that the "cannot build a duplicate" rule you referred to is under "2.a. Build the structure", which is one of the three actions you can do _after_ you've picked a card. The limitation for duplicates is not mentioned under choosing a card (step 1), nor is it mentioned under the other two possible actions. So yes, if you pick a duplicate in the draft, you can stash it in your wonder, or discard it for cash. (Of course, if you want to be strict, you could state that trying to build a duplicate (instead of immediately discarding) is an illegal action, and results in a forfeit.)

Comment: @BillN No, as the wonder instructs you to "build the structure", which is a different action from "discarding for 3 coins". On the corner case where you build your wonder and all cards in the discard pile are duplicates of the ones you already have in play... well, nothing happens. It's just as if the discard pile was empty.